# How to filter a stream using short syntax, when the values are primitives

Tags: javascript, bacon.js

When I have a stream of objects, e.g.

```
 values = Bacon.fromArray([ {'status':"active"},  {'status':"inactive"} ]);
```

I can apply a short form filter, like this:

```
 activeStates = values.filter( ".status", "active" );
```

But when the original stream contains only primitives:

```
 states = Bacon.fromArray( ["active", "inactive" ] );
```

Then I can no longer use that form, and I have to write a function literal. I have tried using `"."`, `""`, `null`, for the property name argument but that doesn't work.

I can define a function like this:

```
    function equals( val ){
        return function( obj ){
            return obj === val;
        }
    }
```

And then write:

```
activeStates = values.filter( equals( "active" ) );
```

Is this the best I can do? Or is there either a Bacon function that I'm missing, or a common lodash function that saves me from writing my own `equals` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Bacon.matchers](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.matchers) library to implement such filters.

```
Bacon.fromArray( ["active", "inactive" ] )
  .where().equalTo("active")
  .onValue(function(val) {
      document.body.innerHTML += val
  })
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omahlama/3mvm8k2y/)